# Issue with unwanted numbers in HTML table

Tags: php, html, html-table, numbers

I have this issue with my HTML table: It is a table of grades, and I used -1 as a pilot grade that means the student hasn't done the exam yet, therefore he didn't get his grade yet. But I don't want it to show up in the table like this:

[image]

I want it to have a blank space there. But SQL won't let me leave it null, and I already did all the corner-cases checking with -1. What should I do to make this disappear?

This is a final project for cs50 course, and I am using one of their distribution code as base. Please ignore the image on top, this is a prototype!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to create a class like gradeX (where X is the grade to be introduced in that cell) and add something like this in the CSS: (In my case, I dont want it to show if the grade is == -1 so)

```
div.grade-1{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

And the table will look something like this:

```
<tr class="d1">
            <td><?= $row["subject"] ?></td>
            <td><div class = "grade<?php echo $row['G1']; ?>"><?= $row["G1"] ?></div></td>
            <td><div class = "grade<?php echo $row['G2']; ?>"><?= $row["G2"] ?></div></td>
            <td><div class = "grade<?php echo $row['G3']; ?>"><?= $row["G3"] ?></div></td>
            <td><div class = "grade<?php echo $row['G4']; ?>"><?= $row["G4"] ?></div></td>
            <td><?= $row["normal"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["creditos"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["criteria"] ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Where the variables starting with $row are the nummbers to be inserted in the table!

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="grade-1">
    <span class="grade">-1</span>
</td>

<td class="grade-50">
    <span class="grade">50</span>
</td>

<td class="grade-100">
    <span class="grade">100</span>
</td>

<style>
   .grade-1 .grade {
       display: none;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I dont know which tables entries are going to be -1. Because it is the user that edits the table. So I did this:
`<td class = "grade<?php echo $row['G1']; ?>"><?= $row["G1"] ?></td>`
In every grade entry. then in style I used: `td.grade-1{display: none;}`
The problem in doing that is that it brings the other entries to the left like this:
http://imgur.com/QZmU1td